# Azure automatically edit resource after deployment

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to create an automation with an event grid on a subscription so that whenever a resource is deployed it will send the event to a webhook that belongs to a runbook that adds a tag to the resource.

(resource deployed -> event grid -> runbooks webhook -> add tag)

However, when I add the tag it triggers a similar event which triggers the event grid again and a cycle begins. The event grid only allow write/action success type of event and there is no way of filtering only the creation events from the other event created by editing the resource.

I want to know if there's a workaround or maybe an alternative to using automation (I don't want to use a modify policy because I want to change other fields in the future not just change tags)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Policy for that although you say you don't want. With a custom Azure Policy, you can modify the different properties of a resource.
Another advantage is that Azure Policy is free whereas you will pay for Automation Account.

On the other hand, for your current situation, I guess the Event Grid is triggered even when the resource is modified. So you need to modify that in order to avoid the loop.

Comment: How would you use Azure Policy to modify the object after deployment automatically?

Comment: You can use modify such as https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Tags/AddTag_ResourceGroup_Modify.json

Comment: let me know if that helps you

Comment: Problem is modify policies can only edit tags

Comment: @TamirBoker nope. Modify is used to add, update, or remove properties or tags on a subscription or resource during creation or update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#modify